# Adding client-unique record to a log event, fluentd side. E.g., using filter

Tags: docker, fluentd

I succeeded getting a dockerized fluentd TCP logging to run! Meaning: There are
remote python containers using a slightly modified
`logging.handlers.SocketHandler` to send some JSON to fluentd - and
it actually arrives there, looking like this:

```
2020-08-31T09:06:31+00:00 paws.tcp {"service_uuid":"paws_log","loglvl":"INFO","file":"paws_log.paws_log","line":59,"msg":"Ping log line #2"}
```

I have multiple such python containers and would like to have fluentd add some
kind of source id to each log event. [Reading the docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/logging) made me give the `filter -> record`
mechanism a chance. Leading to the following config snippet with a **newly added
`filter` block**:

```xml
<source>
  @type tcp
  @label stream_paws
  @id paws_tcp
  tag paws.tcp
  port 5170
  bind 0.0.0.0
  # https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<service_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+): (?<logtime>[^\s]+) (?<loglvl>[^\s]+) \[(?<file>[^\]:]+):(?<line>\d+)\]: (?<msg>.*)$/
    time_key logtime
    time_format %H:%M:%S
    types line:integer
  </parse>
</source>

# Add meta data fluentd side.
# https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/logging
<filter **> # << Does NOT seem to work if kept outside the label-block! Inside is fine.
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    host "#{Socket.gethostname}"
  </record>
</filter>

<label stream_paws>
  <match paws.tcp>
    @type file
    @id output_paws_tcp
    path /fluentd/log/paws/data/tcp.*.log
    symlink_path /fluentd/log/paws/tcp.log
  </match>
</label>
```

I have two questions here:

- Above config works if I put the `filter`-block inside the `label`-block. But this I do not want to do because I want the filter to act globally. `@include` directives might offer a work-around here. Anything better?
- I suspect `"#{Socket.gethostname}"` yields information on the fluentd *server*. However, I want something on the *client*. Ideally including some id that is unique on a docker container level (might be the container id. However, any old client-unique uuid would be fine). Do you know of such a property accessible to fluentd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using fluentd docker logging driver it will already add container metadata (including id) to every log record:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/

> Above config works if I put the filter-block inside the label-block. But this I do not want to do because I want the filter to act globally. @include directives might offer a work-around here. Anything better?

A global filter usually implemented on a server like:

```
<source>
...
</source>

<filter **> # filter globally
...
</filter>

<match tag.one>
...
</match>

<match tag.two>
...
</match>

<match **> # the rest
...
</match>
```

> I suspect "#{Socket.gethostname}" yields information on the fluentd server.

Correct, see: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#example-configurations. This can be useful when you wanna also track which server processed the log record.

Comment: Thx for your answer! So I naively tried adding `cid "#{docker.container_id}"` and `cin "#{docker.container_name}"` to my `record` config. Led to a crashing fluentd container: `undefined local variable docker.` Removing that docker prefix did not help either. Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: P.S.: Now I believe, I get it. Thanks for the link on the docker log driver for fluentd. So your idea is I just log to STDOUT and docker forwards the log to fluentd enriching it with background information along the way? Might be feasible.

Comment: Correct, just log to STDOUT/ERR and you will already have the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kubernetes then use kubernetes metadata it will add pod details with each log entry.

```
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @id filter_kubernetes_metadata
  @type kubernetes_metadata
</filter>
```

**For Docker**

I've not really used fluentd before, so apologies for a slightly abstract response here. But .. checking on http://docs.fluentd.org/ I guess you're probably using in_tail for the logs? From the example there, it looks like you'd probably want to get the path to the file into the input message:

```
path /path/to/file
tag foo.*
```

which apparently tags events with foo.path.to.file

you could probably use http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/filter_record_transformer with enable_ruby. From this, it looks like you could probably process the foo.path.to.file tag and use a little ruby to extract the container ID and then parse out then JSON file.

For example, testing with the following ruby file, say, foo.rb

```
tag = 'foo.var.lib.docker.containers.ID.ID-json.log'
require 'json'; id = tag.split('.')[5]; puts JSON.parse(IO.read("/var/lib/docker/containers/#{id}/config.v2.json"))['image']
```

where config.v2.json was something like:

```
{"image":"foo"}
```

will print you

```
foo
```

Fluentd might already be including json for you, so maybe you could leave out the require 'json'; bit. Then, putting this in fluentd terms, perhaps you could use something like

```
<filter>
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    container ${tag.split('.')[5]}
    image ${id = tag.split('.')[5]; JSON.parse(IO.read("/var/lib/docker/containers/#{id}/config.v2.json"))['image']}
  </record>
 </filter>
```

In your case might be you can use like below

```
<filter raw.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
 <record>
    container ${id = tag.split('.')[5]; JSON.parse(IO.read("/var/lib/docker/containers/#{id}/config.v2.json"))["Name"][1..-1]}
     hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
 </record>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for diving into fluentd doc for me! However, the tag is defined in `fluentd.conf`. Even if I can grab it, it tells nothing new. There are potentially many containers logging to one single `fluentd_ip:port`. They all share the same tag on fluentd side, yet I need to differentiate. What I want to do is to avoid on the client side to add container ids to the log lines -- because I do not want to bother the container software with it being in a docker system. As for the source: I got TCP, HTTP and shared docker volume all up and running. Main method is going to be TCP.